# How to change keystone port#?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, keystonejs

I already have another node CMS app running on default port 3000.I know that when creating a node app we specify the port# in index or app.js. In package.json the start is: node keystone.js but when i do that it says that port is already in use, which is by my other CMS app. I've already check the gulp file. This is a keystonejs getting start CMS

There files are in the main directory:
.env file
gulpfile
keystone.js which is the main file
procfile

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keystone uses the `port` setting which falls back to `process.env.PORT`, `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` and ultimately `3000`.
There's a number of ways you can change this, either by setting the `port` in your `keystone.js` file, like this:

```
keystone.init({
    name: 'My App',
    brand: 'My App',
    port: 3010
    //...
});
```

or

```
keystone.set('port', 3010);
```

Or you can set the `PORT` environment variable in your `.env` file:

```
PORT=3010
```

The latter one has my preference, since that way I can assign different ports on different environments.

Comment: I used the last preference of your answer. It worked to perfection.  Using the PORT=3010 in my .env file:   that was awesome, thanks a lot.

Comment: @padawancoder glad it helped! Could you "accept" my answer, to make it clear a solution was found?

Comment: Dude thank you so much again. With this, now i have like 3 apps humming along at the same time.